# Python Regex to extract variable

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract 2 variables from a string in the following form

```
2015-11-07 10:04:30,855 INFO - RequestTimeLogger.logRequestTime(11) | Request to 'Get Cases (Between Dates)' took 514ms
```

I am trying to extract `Get Cases (Between Dates)` and the response time `514`

I have tried the following using Python 2.7.6

```
reg = re.compile("(.+')(?P<request_name>.*)(' took )(?P<request_time>\d+)(.*)")
reg.match(mystringabove)
```

which returns `false`... What am I doing wrong?

---

The request name is always within quotes like `'something'` and can be any character that isn't a quote
The request time is always before `ms`

Comment: Try this simple regex [`'([^']+)'.*?(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/jR8mQ7/1)

Comment: Use raw strings: `re.compile(r"(.+')(?P<request_name>.*)(' took )(?P<request_time>\d+)(.*)")`

Comment: Your code works for me. `reg.match()` returns a match object with the named groups matching exactly what you want.  (also tested on https://regex101.com/#python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use raw string for the pattern (`r""` format):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r".+'(?P<request_name>[^']*)' took (?P<request_time>\d+)ms")
test_str = "2015-11-07 10:04:30,855 INFO - RequestTimeLogger.logRequestTime(11) | Request to 'Get Cases (Between Dates)' took 514ms\n"
g = p.match(test_str).groupdict()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use search instead of match so you don't have to match the entire string.

```
import re
s="2015-11-07 10:04:30,855 INFO - RequestTimeLogger.logRequestTime(11) | Request to 'Get Cases (Between Dates)' took 514ms"

mat = re.search(r'Request to \'(.*)\' took (.*)ms',s)
if mat:
    print mat.group(1) + ' ' + mat.group(2)

Get Cases (Between Dates) 514
```